# Ubuntu 16.04 takes too much time to boot (Error - lvmetad is not active yet)

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, lvm

Recently my hard disk was crashed and I bought a new one. I reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04 on it with default configuration-

/  499 GB LVM partition
/swap 5.99 GB
//boot 597 MB

On every boot I recieve this error

> lvmetad is not active yet using direct activation during sysinit ubuntu

After that it stuck there for a while. After that it reaches logon screen and stucks there too.

I hace checked other solutions regarding the lvmetad problem but they are not working. Specifically adding "nomodeset" to grub file.

Here is [dmesg log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/21907293/)
Here is systemd-analyze blame results

```
21.787s plymouth-quit-wait.service
      5.236s NetworkManager.service
      4.996s ModemManager.service
      4.605s accounts-daemon.service
      4.377s dev-mapper-ubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2droot.device
      3.190s gpu-manager.service
      2.504s apparmor.service
      1.917s polkitd.service
      1.544s lvm2-monitor.service
      1.516s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-094fb1b3\x2dbbc5\x2d4d40\x2d98
      1.427s bluetooth.service
      1.426s rsyslog.service
      1.414s keyboard-setup.service
      1.348s apport.service
      1.331s networking.service
      1.278s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-F881\x2d89EF.service
      1.266s console-setup.service
      1.233s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      1.183s irqbalance.service
      1.154s avahi-daemon.service
      1.078s systemd-rfkill.service
      1.006s iio-sensor-proxy.service
       969ms dev-mqueue.mount
```

Another problem is that Ubuntu creates one partition during installation so I have no way to backup my data.

Possible solutions I want are-
1. Replace LVM partitioning with ext4.
2. Fix the lvmetad error.
3. Or as a last resort reinstall Ubuntu or another distro.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. I see a message similar to this (A, B, X & Y are numbers) after upgrading my xubuntu to 16.04:

> lvmetad is not active yet; using direct activation during sysinit
>
> /dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-root: clean, X/Y files, A/B blocks

I have kernel: 4.4.0.31 and two logical volumes - swap and root - which was unchanged from 14.04 LTS.

Unlike others with the problem, boot-up to login seems OK. Of interest is the fact that my "systemd-analyze blame" has the same two lines as above indicating that lvm starts after fsck:

> 3.244s lvm2-monitor.service
>
> 3.191s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service

I propose that fsck generates the warning because it is trying to check the disks before lvm has started automatically.

None of: boot.log, kern.log, syslog or dmesg seem to contain anything helpful.

I have been searching for solutions and have found people with problem graphics drivers, raid systems, encrypted disks and unusual backup strategies; none of which apply.

Any help welcome.

Marv

Comment: FWIW Booting with kernel 3.13.0.92 abolishes the warning.